# sklearn Cross validation score gives the same results for every number of folds

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I can't figure out why cross validation gives me always the same accuracy (0.92), no matter how much folds i use.

Even when i delete parameter cv=10 it gives me the same result.

```
#read preprocessed data
traindata = ast.literal_eval(open('pretprocesirano.txt').read())
testdata = ast.literal_eval(open('pretprocesiranoTEST.txt').read())

#create word vector
vectorizer= CountVectorizer(tokenizer=lambda x:x.split(), min_df=3, max_features=300)
traindataCV=vectorizer.fit_transform(traindata)

#save wordlist
wordlist=vectorizer.vocabulary_

#save vectorizer
SavedVectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=wordlist)

#transform test data
testdataCV=SavedVectorizer.transform(testdata)

#modeling-NaiveBayes  
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(traindataCV, label_train) 

#cross validation score
CrossValScore = cross_val_score(clf, traindataCV, label_train, cv=10)
print("Accuracy CrossValScore: %0.3f" %CrossValScore.mean())
```

I tried this way too, and i also got the same results (0.92). This happens even when i change the number of folds, or remove it.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
CrossValScore = cross_val_score(clf, traindataCV, label_train, cv=KFold(10, shuffle=False, random_state=0))
print("Accuracy CrossValScore: %0.3f" %CrossValScore.mean())
```

Here are some samples:

```
traindata= ['ucg investment bank studying unicredit intesa paschi merger sole', 'mtoken sredstva autentifikacije intesa line umesto mini cda cega line vise moze koristi aktivacija', 'pll intesa', 'intesa and unicredit banka asset management the leading italia lenders are both after more fee income but url', 'about write intesa scene colbie cailat fosterthepeople that involves sexy taj between these url']

testdata= ['naumovic samo privilegovani nije delatnosti moci imati hit nama traziti depozit rimuje mentionpositive', 'breaking unicredit board okays launch bad loans vehicle with intesa kkr read more url', 'postoji promocija kupovina telefon rate telefon banka popust pretplata url', 'direktor politike haha struja obecao stan svi zaposliti kredit komercijalna banka', 'forex update unicredit and intesa pool bln euros bad loans kkr vehicle url']

label_train=[0 1 0 0 0]
label_test=[1 0 1 1 0]
```

Comment: Can you give some samples of data?

Comment: Yes, you can see it in the post now.

Comment: Ahh, now that I take a look at your code more closely. Its because cv = someNumber will still be a KFold, with shuffle parameter off. So everytime, it will split the data into same train and test. So the mean will be always be same however many times you run the code. It will only change when you change the n_split or cv to a different number.

Comment: If you want different results for same number of splits, then use shuffle=True in the KFold and remove the random_state, because random_state also fixes the seed which ultimately leads to same folds each time you run the code.

Comment: Also please look at your `vocabulary_`. How many values does it contain?

Comment: It has 300 items, why? As for your answer, i don't want different accuracy for the same number of folder, i want different accuracy for different number of folds.

Comment: Because for the samples you gave, using your CountVectorizer and tokenizer, my wordlist only contained a single word.

Comment: I couldn't provide the whole sample because it has about 5k insances.